# Does movement end when you land on an open gate?

Tags: arkham-horror

If you have 5 Speed and use 1 to move into a location that has an open portal does your movement end or do you continue on into the gate?

Similarly if you use your last movement point and land on an open gate are you unable to go into the gate until the next movement (and in this case have a separate Encounter on the Arkham location)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two different forms of movement in Arkham Horror.  These are described on page 6 of [the rulebook](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Arkham_Horror/Support/Arkham_Horror_Rules_Lo-Res.pdf).

They are:

- Arkham Movement
- Other World Movement

Each investigator must choose which they will use based on where they are located at the beginning of their movement.

If you are using Arkham Movement, use your speed points to move as you will.  Of course you need to stop if you fight a monster.  Other than that, there are few limits.

You do not use speed points to go through a gate.  Going through a gate is typically done during *Phase III: Arkham Encounters*

Comment: So the steps would be 1) Movement: onto gate in Arkham even with leftover Speed; 2) Encounter: go into gate and have other world encounter; 3) Finish round?

Comment: @riv_rec - Basically, yes.  The steps for each round are: Upkeep, Movement, Arkham Encounters, Off-World Encounters, Mythos.  Each player does each phase before going onto the next phase.